# Extract Modified Content of File using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have have 2 Files which contain more than 10 Million of lines and i want to compare those 2 file in efficient way, in my case i am trying to get following answers using **awk** and i am stuck with getting Modified content part

```
Sample FIle (a1.txt)
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4

Sample FIle (b1.txt)   
B,2
C,55 <- Mod data
D,4
E,5  <- new data
F,6  <- new data
Z,11 <- new data
```

*** **A,1 Removed and Modification only apply for Column 2**

Here is my code and expected output

**Newly added content - working fine**

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{++a[$1];next} {line++;if(!(a[$1])){print $0}}' a1.txt b1.txt 

E,5
F,6
Z,11
```

**Removed Content - working fine**

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{++a[$1];next} {line++;if(!(a[$1])){print $0}}' b1.txt a1.txt

A,1
```

**Modified Content**

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2];next} {line++;if(!(a[$2])){print $0}}' a1.txt b1.txt
```

**Current Output (Not required)**

```
C,55
E,5
F,6
Z,11
```

**but required output**

```
C,55
```

This will return bot Newly added content + Modified content

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: Please add expected output as it is not clear here.

Comment: if data is sorted in both files, does the `diff` or `comm` utilities help? `man diff; man comm` . Good luck.

Comment: So you mean to say you want those lines which are not present in file2 and present in file1? Then please explain what is that new data thing in your post?

Comment: actually i want to get modified item , in above example a1.txt contain C,3 but b1.txt it change to C,55 , only i want to get this change

Comment: @Kavinda, so you mean b1.txt contains some other value other than c,3? Could you please give more realistic samples, so that we could understand it more.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Shen Yudong provided the correct answer , appreciate you support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} {line++;if(a[$1] != $2 && a[$1]){print $0}}' v1 v2
C,55


cat v1
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4

cat v2
B,2
C,55
D,4
E,5 
F,6 
Z,11
```